# Приложение вылетает из за layout manager

Tags: java, android, xml

```
public class CaptionedImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] captions;
    private int[] imageIds;
    public CaptionedImagesAdapter(String[] captions, int[] imageIds){
        this.captions = captions;
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(cardView.getContext(), imageIds[position]);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        imageView.setContentDescription(captions[position]);
        TextView textView = (TextView)cardView.findViewById((R.id.info_text));
        textView.setText(captions[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_captioned_image, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return  captions.length;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder(CardView v){
            super(v);
            cardView = v;
        }
    }
}
```

код адаптера

```
public class PizzaFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView pizzaRecycler = (RecyclerView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza, container, false);
    String[] pizzaNames = new String[Pizza.pizzas.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pizzaNames.length; i++){
        pizzaNames[i] = Pizza.pizzas[i].getName();
    }
    int[] pizzaImages = new int[Pizza.pizzas.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pizzaImages.length; i++){
        pizzaImages[i] = Pizza.pizzas[i].getImageId();
    }
    CaptionedImagesAdapter adapter = new CaptionedImagesAdapter(pizzaNames, pizzaImages);
    pizzaRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    pizzaRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    return pizzaRecycler;
    }
    }
```

- код фрагмента, содержащего RecyclerView и layoutManager. Другие активности/фрагменты не задействуются в смысле этой ошибки, а также не вижу смысла приводить код макета т. к. там тоже все ясно. Еще раз повторюсь, когда убираю layout manager - все работает.

  ```
    public class Pizza {
    private String name;
    private int imageId;
    public static final Pizza[] pizzas = {
            new Pizza("Маргорита", R.drawable.margorita),
            new Pizza("Пицца с грибами", R.drawable.mashrooms)
    };
    private Pizza(String name, int ImageId){
        this.name = name;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
  ```

  }

Этим инициализирую массив imageIds[].

Проблема заключается в том что вылетает приложение при добавлен layout manager любового вида. Для recycler view написан адаптер, код xml для фрагмента также написан, причем раньше приложение не вылетало. Добавляю layout manager - крашится, убираю все ок. Не вижу смысла отправлять код, поэтому отправлю логкат. Надеюсь на решении моей проблемы. Заранее спасибо[image: описание проблемы]

Comment: приложите код ошибки в виде текста, а так же добавьте код класса на который ссылается ошибка с пометкой проблемной строки, но судя по ошибке у вас проблема с каким-то id, покажите что и как вы добавляете

Comment: в адатпере какой контект используете? context или appContext? Если appContext попробуйте заменить его на contextю И все-таки код пожалуйста в студию, мало ли вы ошибку не замечаете, глаз замылился

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев я изменил вопрос и добавил нужные материалы

Comment: Возможно проблема в `int[] imageIds` - покажите ещё что вы передаёте в этом массиве - т.е. покажите чем инициализируете. Судя по логам - вы там 0 передаёте и потому оно и падает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в инициализации pizzas. В момент, когда вы создаете массив, id картинок равны 0x0. Попробуйте создать массив в onCreate и передать его конструктор адаптера. Скорее всего проблема уйдет. Плюс конечно проверьте еще раз картинки.

Comment: А как это сделать в коде?

Comment: для проверки перенесите  public static final Pizza[] в onCreateView(сразу скажу, что это не верно, т.к. мы неправильно используем жизенный цикл фрамегнта, но для теста пойдет)